# jquery simple example change() function

Tags: jquery

I'm just learning jQuery, I'm so noob.

see, we have 2 divs as follows:

```
<div id="div1">
<ul>
    <li> This is Line 1</li>
    <li> This is Line 2</li>
    <li> This is Line 3</li>
    <li> This is Line 4</li>
    <li> This is Line 5</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="div2">
<ul>
    <li> <input type="text" /></li>
    <li> <input type="text" /></li>
    <li> <input type="text" /></li>
    <li> <input type="text" /></li>
    <li> <input type="text" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

since I'm just learning change() function, this is what I want to do:
When each value of input boxes in div2 changes, the div1 li of the same number should be changed to the entered value, for example if we start typing in the second input box in div2, the second li text should go what we entered in the second input box.

here is what i've tried so far, but not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#div2 :input').change(function(i){
            var str = $(this).text;
            $('#div1 li').eq(i).text(str);
        });
    });
</script>
```

what's wrong with this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter passed to the `change()` function isn't the index.  It's an [`event` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).  You need to get the index yourself, using [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Also, [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is the wrong method here, you need to use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of the input.

```
$('#div2 :input').change(function() {
    var str = $(this).val(), // You need to use `val` to get the value (also, note the "()" here)
        index = $(this).parent().index(); // this gets the index of the input
    $('#div1 li').eq(index).text(str);
});​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/skram/UJBCr/1/

Comment: Is `$(this).parent().index();` better or `$(this).index('#div2 :input');`?

Comment: @Rocket mm `$(this).parent().index();` should just work fine too >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/UJBCr/1/ << but not sure if it is any better that `$(this).index('..')`

Comment: @Vega: Yeah, that's probably better.

Comment: @Rocket thanks man, it's now working. I read the index() documentation, but I don't see how parent() is relevant to this case!? why we're using parent(), I'm curious...

Comment: @behz4d: Because `index` called without any parameters searches the element's parent for the element, and returns the position.  So, we need to use `parent()` to get the `<li>`.  Then when `index()` is called, it searches for the `<li>` in its parent (the `<ul>`), and returns the correct positon.

Comment: OK, thanks now it's working.

Now, what if I want the div1 li texts changes at the same time while we're typing in the input boxes? I mean live, not after blur the li text changes...?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) (since you are after text input) not `text()`:

```
 var str = $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `var str = $(this).text`

as

`var str = this.value; //or $(this).val()`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
 $('#div2 :input').change(function(e){
      var i = $('#div2 :input').index(this);
      $('#div1 li').eq(i).text( $(this).val() );
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EAXfF/)

Comment: +1 for actually fixing the issue, and not just pointing out the missing `()`.

Comment: @Rocket I can say same things about your answer ;)